# Spring JPA Dao - Could not autowire field

Tags: java, spring, junit, dao

I'm trying to setup a Junit test to test the JPA configuration. The class is the following:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class OrderPersistenceTests {
    @Autowired
    public JpaDaoRole dr;

    @Transactional
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        Role r = new Role();
        r.setIdRole(18);
        r.setDescription("description");
        dr.persist(r);
        Role r1=dr.findById(r.getIdRole());
        assertEquals(r.getIdRole(), r1.getIdRole());
    }
}
```

here is also my app-context configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <description>Example configuration to get you started.</description>

    <!-- Generic -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.windy.spring" />

    <!-- JPA -->

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/> 
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" /> <!-- Prints used SQL to stdout -->
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" /> <!-- Generates tables. -->
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/windydb"/>
        <property name="username" value="windyuser"/>
        <property name="password" value="123"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

When I try to launch my test I see from my log that the entities class are loaded correctly but the dao classes can not be autowired. My dao implementation is the following;

```
@Repository
public class JpaDaoRole extends JpaDao<Role, Integer> implements DaoRole {

}
```

---

```
public abstract class JpaDao <E, K> implements Dao<E, K> {
    protected Class<E> entityClass;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JpaDao.class);

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public JpaDao() {
        ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        this.entityClass = (Class<E>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        logger.info(this.entityClass.toString());
    }

    public EntityManager name() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public void persist(E entity) { entityManager.persist(entity); }

    public void remove(E entity) { entityManager.remove(entity); }

    public E findById(K id) { return entityManager.find(entityClass, id); }
}
```

the log i sthe following:

```
2012-01-31 00:09:49,456 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3a747fa2: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,jpaDaoRole,jpaDaoUser,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,entityManagerFactory,dataSource,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy>
2012-01-31 00:09:49,492 INFO [com.windy.spring.JpaDao] - <class com.windy.spring.Role>
2012-01-31 00:09:49,538 INFO [com.windy.spring.JpaDao] - <class com.windy.spring.User>
2012-01-31 00:09:49,585 ERROR [org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager] - <Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@629ca1fb] to prepare test instance [com.windy.spring.OrderPersistenceTests@194e9851]>
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.windy.spring.OrderPersistenceTests': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.windy.spring.JpaDaoRole com.windy.spring.OrderPersistenceTests.dr; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.windy.spring.JpaDaoRole] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.windy.spring.JpaDaoRole com.windy.spring.OrderPersistenceTests.dr; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.windy.spring.JpaDaoRole] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.windy.spring.JpaDaoRole] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 28 more
2012-01-31 00:09:49,592 INFO [org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext] - <Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@36b8bef7: startup date [Tue Jan 31 00:09:47 CET 2012]; root of context hierarchy>
2012-01-31 00:09:49,593 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - <Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3a747fa2: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,jpaDaoRole,jpaDaoUser,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,entityManagerFactory,dataSource,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy>
2012-01-31 00:09:49,603 INFO [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] - <Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'application'>
2012-01-31 00:09:49,603 INFO [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] - <closing>
```

I can not understand because is not autowired if I declared the cla jpadao as @repository.

Thanks in advance for your help

Danilo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think in `OrderPersistenceTests` you should be using the interface `DaoRole` and not the actual class.

```
@Autowired
public DaoRole dr;
```

Comment: thanks a lot you are right I should have used the generic implementation.

Comment: had the same problem and your strategy solved it. I always forget to use interfaces when dealing with proxies. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to annotate your test class with @ContextConfiguration and tell spring where the configuration xml is located:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:app-context.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class OrderPersistenceTests {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I added the location to the xml context @ContextConfiguration("app-context.xml") but i still get the same error.

Comment: I tried to modify the class JpaDaoRole in the way that it contains all the Dao logic (all the methods are implemented directly in the class so it does not implemet/extends any class) and my test is working. I thing spring does not like this structure @Repository
public class JpaDaoRole extends JpaDao<Role, Integer> implements DaoRole {
}
I do not understand why? Any help?